# Just address toolbar php get method using

Tags: php, mysql

I do basic e-commerce system. This is my system in not membership, not shopping, just there are visual.

I want to do address toolbar enter to the information. This information, List my query mysql.

My html dropdown menu;

```
<?php
    $cats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
    if($cats === FALSE){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($cats )){
    ?>
        <li><a href="itemCat=<?php echo $row['link'];?>"><?php echo $eow['categoryName']; ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

I want to display the current page with the INNERJOIN to GET my data.

I thought;

```
<?php
    if($_GET['itemCat']=="ctbKopuk"){
        //INNERJOIN with tables
    }
?>
```

How do we do?

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: **Notice:** Undefined index: itemCat

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**warning**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That notice means that there is no `itemCat` in your url.

Check if it exists first, using

```
if (array_key_exists('itemCat', $_GET))
```

Your code would become:

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('itemCat', $_GET) && $_GET['itemCat'] == "ctbKopuk"){
        //INNERJOIN with tables
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am solved!! But, I can't vote, I am sorryy..

Comment: No problem. In time you will. :)